# Using the AWS CLI, how do I get a figure showing how many requests my API Gateway(s) have served?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I've tried a few googled suggestions but they all seem to come back with a Count value of 1, which is obviously incorrect. For clarity, I'm looking to see how many requests (success and errors) the API has served between given dates.

Thanks

Edit: A good suggestion, to include failed commands:

`aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/ApiGateway --metric-name Count --start-time 2021-06-02T09:00:00 --end-time 2021-06-03T09:00:00 --period 3600 --region eu-west-1 --statistics Average --unit Count`

Others were very similar, tweaking the period in most cases as I recall (several were on a VM that has since been destroyed).

Comment: Do you have any of these incorrect commands to show that you tried?

Comment: @Marcin Good point, thank you. Example added.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the Statistic here is Average instead of Sum to get the total count. I got here because I am having issues finding the right way to filter this by api gateway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).